# section sobrepõem meu header

Tags: html5, css3

Quero colocar meu conteúdo logo abaixo da tag *header* porem quando crio a minha section o conteúdo sobrepõem o meu *header* e não sei se e uma boa pratica pegar a minha section e aplicar um *margin-top* segue o código:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
header {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(http://ten2.tw/assets/templates/ten2/images/about-kv.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
header #bg-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
}
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li a {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  color: #1C8AE7;
}
#logo-header {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#texto-header {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-top: -5%;
}
#btn-header {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn-header:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #222;
}
#posicao-header {
  margin-top: -10%;
}
/*********************************************************************
    
       Corpo-1

**********************************************************************/

.corpo-1 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="" charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sobre</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Cases</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Serviços</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Orçamento</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="posicao-header">
      <img src="images/bg-header.png" id="bg-header">

      <p class="text-center">
        <img src="http://www.impulsegamer.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/IMG_3194.png" id="logo-header">
      </p>

      <div id="texto-header">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>

      <p class="text-center">
        <a href="#">
          <input type="button" value="Como podemos ajudar?" id="btn-header">
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="corpo-1">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum <strong>Dolor</strong></h1>
    <h2>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h2>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Obs: o código terá que funcionar semanticamente e nos navegadores Google Chrome, Safari e Mozila.

Comment: Não fique preso a esse negócio que chamam de "boas práticas". Se você possui conhecimento das regras CSS e sabe o que está fazendo, que mal tem aplicar um `margin-top`? Eu acho que nesse caso, você mesmo já respondeu o que fazer. **:D** Eu só olharia mesmo esses `input type="button"` no meio do código HTML, você pode simplesmente utilizar um `<button>`.

Comment: É por causa da `position:absolute;`. Tenta adicionar um `<br style="clear:both;">` entre as 2 tags.

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que o seu `<header>` é o primeiro elemento no corpo da página, não são necessárias (aceitáveis) as seguintes linhas de estilo:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Remova essas linhas para que o `<header>` se coloque de volta no "fluir" da página e empurre os próximos elementos para baixo de si.

Algumas dicas adicionais:

- Estude melhor o que cada propriedade CSS faz realmente.
- Defina um padrão para os seus estilos.
- Um cabeçalho pode ser dividido em seções também. Prefira utilizar uma `<section>` para dividir o `<header>`. Porém como não há mais divisões, eu sugiro que apenas remova aquela `<div>`e deixe o seu conteúdo solto no cabeçalho.
- Prefira reduzir a imagem do cabeçalho manualmente do que fazer "*hacks*" com `position: relative`.
- Não utilize `id` e `class` onde não for realmente necessário.
- Não utilize `<p>` apenas para agrupar ou estilizar conteúdo. Guarde ele para parágrafos de verdade (preferencialmente com texto).

Uma versão um pouco mais semântica com talvez menos bytes do seu código:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
header {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(http://ten2.tw/assets/templates/ten2/images/about-kv.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -2;
  text-align: center;
}
header #bg-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
header ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
}
header ul {
  text-align: center;
}
header ul li a {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
header ul li a:hover {
  color: #1C8AE7;
}
#logo-header {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
  margin-top: 10%;
}
header p {
  text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
      font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;

}

header input[type=button] {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
header input[type=button]:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #222;
}

/*********************************************************************
    
       Corpo-1

**********************************************************************/

.corpo-1 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <meta name="" charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Orçamento</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="images/bg-header.png" id="bg-header">          
            <img src="http://www.impulsegamer.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/IMG_3194.png" id="logo-header">
            <br />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <a href="#"><input type="button" value="Como podemos ajudar?"></a>
            <br />
            <br />
        </header>
        <section class="corpo-1">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum <strong>Dolor</strong></h1>
            <h2>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h2>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```